# TSQL - How do you combine records based on id, on one row, with a carriage return?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

TSQL - How do you combine records based on id, on one row, with a carriage return?

- I'm trying STRING_AGG, but I'm not sure if STUFF would be better as
  STRING_AGG isn't outputting the way I need it to.

**Situation/Requirements:**

- Each employee can have multiple bus stops
- Each employee needs to be listed on only one row
- Each TimeOfDay / BusNumber needs to be separated by a carriage return, in order of TimeAtSrvOrderNum, so when you do 'results to text' in SSMS, it appears as if each busnumber/timeofday is on its own row.

**Sample Data:**  (Each employee has their own color in the data).

[image]

```
    CREATE TABLE #BusInfo
(
    EmployeeID        VARCHAR(10)
  , TimeOfDay         VARCHAR(10)
  , BusNumber         VARCHAR(10)
  , TimeAtSrvOrderNum VARCHAR(10)
)
INSERT INTO #BusInfo(
    EmployeeID
  , TimeOfDay
  , BusNumber
  , TimeAtSrvOrderNum
)
VALUES
 (223344,   'AM',   118,    1)
,(223344,   'AM',   321,    2)
,(223344,   'PM',   321,    3)
,(223344,   'PM',   118,    4)
,(556677,   'AM',   978,    1)
,(556677,   'PM',   439,    2)
,(778899,   'AM',   675,    1)
,(778899,   'AM',   918,    2)
,(778899,   'PM',   111,    3)


SELECT * FROM #BusInfo AS bi
```

**Current Code:**

```
SELECT      bi.EmployeeID
          , STRING_AGG (bi.TimeOfDay + ' ' + bi.BusNumber, CHAR (13)) AS BusInformation
FROM        #BusInfo AS bi
GROUP BY    bi.EmployeeID
ORDER BY bi.TimeAtSrvOrderNum;
```

**Current Results:**

[image: Photo of current results]

Desired Results:

[image: Photo of desired results]

Comment: I tried your code, and it works for me, see this [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=efeb12ab0a406a8094dd6a97ca036491)

Comment: OK, thanks for looking.  I was expecting a different look in SSMS.

Comment: Same here, but the output above is from Print, not Select.

Comment: Should this look the same in a SSRS report?  The requirement is to have the data in the column formatted so the report will pull it pre-formatted.

Comment: Your query does exactly what you are expecting, you're viewing the results as *text* in SSMS - the char(13) puts the subsequent values on a new line irrespective of column formatting, this is just down to how the client (SSMS) is presenting the data.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help everyone.  It looks like formatting will need to happen outside the data.